# Android: Transparent View on top of another View

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to have a (semi-)transparent view on top of another view (a map) where I can place various elements as an overlay. With my current setup I have two problems, as shown in the image below:

[image]

a. the test rectangle appears always at the bottom (as a test I want it 40dp from the top)

b. the view is not entirely transparent, there is a greyish area above my test-rectangle

my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/landmark"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/box"
            android:src = "@drawable/rectangle"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

activity class:

```
class LandmarkActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landmark)
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".LandmarkActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this, without `layout_alignParentBottom` and with proper top margin set

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/landmark"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/box"
        android:src = "@drawable/rectangle"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`ImageView` have `android:src = "@drawable/rectangle"` with sizes set as `wrap_content` so size of this `View` depends on your drawable. you may consider adding `adjustViewBounds` and `scaleType` xml attrs to `ImageView`, but without actual real `rectangle` drawable its hard to guess is this will help